# Interactive 3D human body in JavaScript, AngularJS or Three.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, three.js

I want to create a interactive 3D Human through which we can take inputs by clicking on the body parts.

Is it possible to create it using JavaScript, AngularJS or Three.js

Answer (score 2):

Basically anything is possible with JavaScript.

Going with three.js seems to be the best solution since it's a 3D library.

So the answer to your question would be yes. Will it be easy? Probably not.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_human.html

Comment: How do I turn water into wine with JavaScript?

Comment: @mlkn `if (typeof liquid === 'water') { liquid.convertTo('wine'); }`

Comment: Thanks a lot Chrillewoodz for your response.

Comment: It would be of great help if you could share some links or codes to do the same.

Comment: @user2237857 Only found one example.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.kineman.com/

> KineMan is the ultimate web application for learning and demonstrating human joint behavior, and for creating complex human poses.
>
> Unlike any other online human anatomy/kinesiology model or mannequin app, KineMan allows YOU to move the joints: simply, precisely, and realistically. You can select from over 100 joints (and 170 degrees of freedom), and move them simply by clicking & dragging on the skeleton. You’ll observe biomechanically-realistic behaviors, owing to movement parameters (like ranges of motion) derived from scientific sources.